How to add a placeholder to MUI Select component created by TextField?
I want to add a placeholder (-- Select --) to the following MUI Select component created by TextField with select prop.
const [country, setCountry] = useState("")
<TextField
    select
    value={country}
    onChange={e => setCountry(e.target.value)}
>
    <MenuItem value='US'>America</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value='CA'>Canada</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value='UK'>England</MenuItem>
</TextField>

I've tried to add placeholder='-- Select --' props but the placeholder can't be displayed.
Then I've tried to add label='-- Select --' props. Although the placeholder can be displayed, when the component was rendered initially and I tried to select an option, the label moved to the top-left corner of the component, I don't want that animation. Then I've tried to add InputLabelProps={{disableAnimation: true}}  props but the animation still existed.
Could someone teach me how to add a placeholder in my case?

If we inspect the Select element, there is an empty span inside the div with the class .MuiSelect-select which is visible when there is no value selected.

We can create a work-around solution using this span like this:
const [country, setCountry] = useState('');

return (
    <TextField
      sx={{
        width: '300px',
        '& .MuiSelect-select span::before': {
          content: "'-- Select --'",
        },
      }}
      select
      value={country}
      onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
    >
      <MenuItem value="US">America</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="CA">Canada</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="UK">England</MenuItem>
    </TextField>
);

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example of this work-around solution.

Thank you so much for your solution. I played in your StackBlitz and found that the component only works if content is set to "'-- Select --'" or '"-- Select --"', it doesn't work if content is set to '-- Select --' or "-- Select --". Why is that? @Ahmet Emre Kilinc

The css content property requires the strings to be quoted, and the MUI sx property is an object, we should wrap the string with another quotation mark in order to let the string to be parsed properly.  This SO answer explains this requirement in detail. By the way, could you please accept my answer if it resolves your problem?

Sure, thank you so much for your help. I want to ask an additional question. If I want to implement internationalization to my web page, I've tried to use content: 't("select")' where t comes from const {t} = useTranslation, and "select": "-- Select --" was defined in i18n config file. However, the placeholder can't be displayed. May I know what the problem is? @Ahmet Emre Kilinc

Thank you. I've forked and updated the stackblitz and added the example of i18next support. You can take a look at it.

Thank you so much for your solution and you're very helpful. Currently I'm creating a form using React-Hook-Form but I encounter a big difficulty of using the library when implementing my custom features of the form. Would you please help check my another question posted in the following link? @Ahmet Emre Kilinc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78503414/can-react-hook-form-library-be-used-to-create-forms-in-any-formats?noredirect=1#comment138398024_78503414
